# How to copy custom attribute from all inputs in the form and then assign back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do have a form with a lot of inputs (text, selectbox, submit, etc).. There are 2 buttons on the form, when first one is clicked I want to copy the custom attribute from all inputs and if the second button is clicked I want to assign those attributes back if that custom attribute is empty (="").

What I have as of now:

- A form (`#myForm`) with dozens of `inputs`
- A function which unassignes custom attribute if the input does not have a specific class named as `.dontcheck`

  ```
  $(':input','#myForm')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, .dontcheck')
  .attr("customAttribute","");
  ```

So, when the first button is clicked I should copy all inputs' `customAttribute` and clear the `customAttribute` if it does not have the `.dontcheck` class. I have the clean part but I dont know how to copy and then assign the `customAttribute` back to each input with it's own unique `id`.

I'm new to JQuery world, any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: @user2783091, it was more than I could ask for.. also I learned few more things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var   customAttrList;

 function deleteCustomAttr(){   var elementToDeleteAttr = $(':input','#myForm')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, .dontcheck');

 customAttrList = {};

  $.each(elementToDeleteAttr, function(index, item){
         customAttrList [item.id] = $(item).attr("customAttribute");//copy attributes and save by Id
         $(item).attr("customAttribute", "");
  });


}
 function returnAttrBack(){
       var elementToBackAttr = $(':input','#myForm')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, .dontcheck');

 $.each(elementToBackAttr , function(index, item){
         $(item).attr("customAttribute", customAttrList[item.id]);//get attribute by Id

  });

 }
```